# Typescript - convert array.map to array

Tags: typescript, devextreme-angular

I wanted to emulate C# Linq select. And bind result to Devextreme DataGrid.

I get objects implemented:

```
export interface A { b: B[]; }
export interface B { c: C; }
```

I can make an array by collecting all the Cs and DataGrid works fine with `test1`:

```
let test1 = [];

for (var k in this.a.b)
  test1.push(this.a.b[k].c);
```

But if I try map as masses of blogs suggest for linq.Select the DataGrid doesn't display any data with `test2`:

```
let test2 = a.b.map(i => i.c);
```

Question - is result of array.map an array?

Comment: yes, it is still an array after map, what is the output of test2?

Comment: In debugger they look the same. But datagrid doesn't like test2

Answer (score 0):

They both have the same contents and point to the same objects (c objects in this case), however are different arrays. To compare equality for an array of objects, you would want to iterate over each element and verify equivalence.

```js
const isEqual<T extends object>(a: T[], b: T[]): boolean {
   // ... iterate and check each value
}
```

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear enough. I had to edit it